# Reverse engineering Delphi code - UML

Tags: delphi, uml, delphi-xe4

I am totally new to UML and I am using the trial version of Delphi XE4 currently. I am trying to create UML design for my project which is built using Delphi 2009. When I open project in Delphi XE4, I am able to see Class diagram in "Model View" option for each pas file but there is no relationship among the classes. There are more than 100 pas files in my project.

I am not clear is it possible to get all UML diagrams automatically? Or I need to create it each diagram manually?

Basically i want to know how much complecated my current project is to migrate to JAVA. i wanted to perform Reverse Engineering.

Comment: It sounds like you want to avoid learning Delphi, by looking at an UML representation and then applying that in Java. I have to disappoint you. If you need to update this software you'll have to dive into the code and make sure you understand what it does. Porting it to Java is even going to force you to read and understand every single line of the original code.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I really dont wanted to avoid Delphi, i wanted to stick with it. But vendor wants in Java or any other technology and dont have option right now. I am having idea about what code does and all. We are trying to find how much complicated it will be moving to other technology. Thats why I need UML diagrams to visualize the complexity.I was not clear it all diagrams will get created automatically? I searched on net but didnt found any valuable materiable which gives me idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the IDE's built in UML diagram support does not reverse engineer code into diagrams. Various third party tools claim this ability, for example ModelMaker, Enterprise Architect, Rational Rose, etc.

Comment: I can attest to ModelMaker's capabilities in this respect. Have used them in the past and found them very useful.

Comment: @Marjan No matter how good the tool is, would expect to get much sense out of auto created diagrams of 100+ source files? I'm not sure any tool could shed meaningful light on this. But I ask since I personally have little experience of diagram use.

Comment: No, not from auto-created diagrams. No auto-generated diagram will ever be really helpful unless done for some very trivial code. But they are a starting point. My approach was to load everything up in ModelMaker, identify the core classes/interfaces, and start diagramming from those in ModelMaker myself. It is a nice way to familiarize yourself with a code base. Especially as you don't have to worry about units anymore (unless you intend to re-generate the source as MM is a fully 2-way tool).

Comment: As an excersize, try to visualize a 15 line quicksort procedure in UML, or create a full class diagram of an application with a form with a single button only. You'll quickly realize that UML is only useful in specific situations, and that code (even pascal) is a pretty efficient method to describe and specify algorithms.